# What is the partial derivative with respect to x of another derivative squared?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I am just wondering how the following equation would resolve: $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}{EA[(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x})+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x})^3]}$$

The first part seems easy enough, as it would just be the product rule, correct? However, I'm not sure how to go about solving the second part given the exponent. If anyone could provide some help, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are $E$ and $A$ constants?  If so, you just use chain rule on the second term.

Comment: Are you trying to take the partial on $x$ of all that stuff, or is some of this just multiplication?

Comment: @DMcMor So would it just resolve to $\frac{3}{2}EA(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x})^2(\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2})$?

Comment: @Randall It is the partial derivative wrt x of the entire expression

Comment: You need the product rule on the first bit, the chain rule on the second.

Comment: That would be be the second term after differentiating, yes.